# MultiIndexing in pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the below dataframe output by using pandas `crosstab` function and then doing a tohtml() to get in table form. But I need to get my DF in the right form first

```
out = pd.crosstab(df1[lurn_FLS'], df1['LOCALITY'])
out['Total'] = out.sum(axis=1)
total_sum = out[ 'Total'].sum()
out['Percentage'] = ((out ['Total'/total_sum) *100).round(2)
print(out)
```

| Locality | mbn:match_both_non-empty | xne:mismatch neither empty | Total | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lurn_fls |  |  |  |  |
| -------- | ------------------------- | -------------------------- | ------ | ------------ |
| 1 | 210 | 300 | 510 | 21 |
| 2 | 310 | 400 | 710 | 50 |

I want the table header to look like below with actual column headers sitting on the first row of the table

```
| Locality |  |  |  |  |
| -------- | -------------------------| -------------------------- | ------|------------|         
| lurn_fls | mbn:match_both_non-empty | xne:mismatch neither empty | Total | Percentage |
| -------- | -------------------------| -------------------------- | ------|------------|                                
| 1        | 210                      | 300                        | 510   | 21         |
| 2        | 310                      | 400                        | 710   | 50         |
```

Is there any solution to get the table headers in the expected format in the dataframe? TIA

Comment: Why are you using single quote `'Total'`?

Comment: Do you just want to `reset_index`?

Comment: yes I want to reset/re do the headers in such a way that the column values get displayed directly 1 row above the actual data rows .

Answer (score 1):

html like this？[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9oq2.png)

code:

```
out = pd.crosstab(
    df1["lurn_FLS"],
    df1["LOCALITY"],
    margins=True,
    margins_name="Total",
    colnames=[None],
).reset_index()
out["Percentage"] = out["Total"].divide(out["Total"].iloc[-1]).mul(100).round(2)
)
newcols = out.columns.map(lambda x: ("LOCALITY", x))
out.columns = newcols
out = out.iloc[:-1]
out.to_html("out.html", index=False)
```